# Fourier Transform to Solve an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I am having trouble understanding how to use Fourier transforms to solve ODEs and came across this problem in some exercises from the text I am learning from:

Use Fourier transforms to solve $-u_{xx}+a^2u=\delta$ where $\delta=\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.

I would appreciate if someone could help me solve this and could provide some general outline on how to solve DEs like these with Fourier transforms. Thanks.

Comment: How far do you get if you disregard all operator-commutativity and convergence concerns? Do you know (how to look up in a table) what the transform of the second derivative is?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I did not understand your first question, but would the second derivative's transform be $-k^2 u$?

Comment: The usual trick is to transform the differential equation using that $$ \widehat{f^{(n)}}(\xi)=(2\pi i)^n \widehat f(\xi)$$. The resulting differential equation is usually easy to solve.

Comment: Yes. (Depending on how the constants of the transform are distributed). Now insert to get $(k^2+a^2)\hat u(k)=1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh wow I see now, thanks a lot. But regarding the delta function, do I have to worry about anything changing for the solution at different places?

Comment: @sampleuser thanks, that is helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You get something like $u(x)=ce^{-|ax|}$ as solution, where the place of the singularity coincides with the place of the delta peak.